# How to create a Matlab/Simulink MEX file to save signal to the workspace

Tags: matlab, simulink, mex

I'm new to C-Mex routines and seeking some direction.

How do I create a C-Mex file to save a simulink signal to the Matlab workspace. The function is to be the same as the Simulink block 'To Workspace'.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to re-create a functionality that already exists?

Answer (score 2):

Use `mexPutVariable` to write into the base workspace, but unless you have very good reasons use the predefined block.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. So, I think this function should be used within the mdlTerminate(SimStruct *S) routine?